# How can I add blacks to an image, akin to what Photoshop does?

Tags: java, image-processing

[image]

[image]I have an array of rgb values, and I want to directly modify those values rather than using a RescaleOp because I have more control that way.

```
for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
                int[] rgb = image.getRGB([x][y]);
                rgb[0] *= Math.pow(2, desiredBrightness);
                rgb[1] *= Math.pow(2, desiredBrightness);
                rgb[2] *= Math.pow(2, desiredBrightness);
            }
}
```

That is my for loop for modifying brightness, and I'm trying to use a similar one for adding blacks but I can't come up with a similar algorithm to the one above.

Comment: what do you mean "add blacks" -  you have to explain explicitly

Comment: @gpasch In Adobe Bridge there is a slider for making dark colors darker, Which is labelled "Blacks" while making very little difference to the lighter colors. It's like contrast but without modifying the lighter colors very much.

Comment: ok i dont use photoshop etc so if you have two images before after I could understand post them here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need a cut-off approach/function: you find the colors that are near or very close to black (all color components need to be below a certain threshold) and you turn them completely black:

```
addBlacks(int blackThreshold) {
  for (x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
      int rgb = bim.getRGB(x, y)&0x00ffffff;
      int rr=(rgb&0x00ff0000)>>16, rg=(rgb&0x0000ff00)>>8, rb=rgb&0x000000ff;
    if(rr<blackThreshold && rg<blackThreshold && rb<blackThreshold)
      rr=rg=rb=0;
    b2.setRGB(x, y, 0xff000000|(rr<<16)|(rg<<8)|rb);
  }
}
```

at 35 you should start seeing effects and at 55 definitely, with the given image. And you can create interesting effects by applying different cut-off thresholds to different components R, G, B.